# ROS2 rmw_connext_cpp in raspberry system (armhf)

Tags: ros, ros2, armhf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

ROS2 rmw_connext_cpp dependents RTI connext dds, but missing some library about
librticonnextmsgcppd.so in armhf system. However, this library can be found in amd64 system.
The RMW rmw_connext_cpp will be available if no librticonnextmsgcppd.so.

How to install the RTI library like librticonnextmsgcppd.so in armhf system?
Is rti-connext-dds not supported in ROS2 repository in arm system now?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319859/ros2-rmw_connext_cpp-in-raspberry-system-(armhf)/) by [braddly](https://answers.ros.org/users/40654/braddly/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you look at "ROS 2.0 Target Platforms" from REP #2000:
http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html

As of ROS2 Crystal, you'll find the table listing the "Middleware Implementation Support", where rmw_connext_cpp is supported for "All (targeted) Architectures except arm64". No pre-compiled release binaries are available for armhf (i.e. arm32v7) as its not listed among the targeted architectures. You'd also have to contact RTI for arm32 releases of DDS Connext, as I don't think the download for it is publicly distributed.

There was a community request for arm32v7 support, however has yet to gain traction with release maintainers:
https://discourse.ros.org/t/official-docker-images-for-ros2-crystal-and-arm32v7/6872

However, if your using a raspberry pi 3, there are arm64v8 images you could use so you could install ROS2 from the release arm64 debains:
https://discourse.ros.org/t/installing-ubuntu-18-04-arm64v8-on-raspberry-pi-3/6094/8

---

Originally posted by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) with karma: 1094 on 2019-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [braddly](https://answers.ros.org/users/40654/braddly/) on 2019-04-12**:
Got it, thanks.

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on 2019-04-12**:
Please remember to mark your questions as solved by selecting the appropriate answer, so that both answered and unanswered questions may be more visible.